# Назначение обработчиков нескольким кнопкам QPushButton

Tags: python, pyqt5, lambda, сигналы-слоты, qpushbutton

Простое приложение на *PyQt5* с двумя кнопками.

Вот так работает:

```
def add_handlers(self):
    self.pushButton_1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.btn_handler('one'))
    self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.btn_handler('two'))

def btn_handler(self, i):
    print('handler:', i)
```

---

а так нет:

```
def add_handlers(self):
    for btn, word in zip((self.pushButton_1, self.pushButton_2), ('one', 'two')):
        btn.clicked.connect(lambda x=word: self.btn_handler(i=x))

def btn_handler(self, i):
    print('handler:', i)
```

---

Помогите понять, почему во втором случае не работает? 
В *Tkinter* такое прокатывало.

Answer (score 1):

Пожалуйста, всегда предоставляйте минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который демонстрирует проблему.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *   


class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()   

        self.pushButton_1 = QPushButton('Button_1')
        self.pushButton_2 = QPushButton('Button_2')
        
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout(self)  
        self.layout.addWidget(self.pushButton_1) 
        self.layout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2) 
        
        self.add_handlers()
        
    def add_handlers(self):
        for btn, word in zip(
            (self.pushButton_1, self.pushButton_2), 
            ('one', 'two')
        ):
            btn.clicked.connect(lambda ch, x=word: self.btn_handler(i=x))
# -----------------------------------> ^^ <---------------------------------

    def btn_handler(self, i):
        print(f'handler: {i}\n')
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName("WebCam")
    window = MyWidget()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: так действительно работает, спасибо,
но если ch убрать то не будет,
не могу понять почему

Comment: @AntonRyabenko `ch` - это мое сокращение `checked`. Читаем https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractbutton.html#clicked